# PHP mySQL structure output tree

Tags: php, mysql, tree, join

I'm trying to optimize a many to many design which will return a tree like structure. The data looks like this:

pages table:  id, title, subtitle, class
pages connector table: id, page_id, parent_id, section

if section = x, for each parent which has children where section = x markup should be something like:

```
--- start parent 1 ---
 -- if first parent echo *
<>* parent page id | parent title<>
--- parent 1 children --- 
   <>child page id | child title<>
   <>child page id | child title<>
   <><>child page id | child title<>
--- end parent 1 ---
--- start parent 2 ---
 -- if first parent echo *
<>parent page id | parent title<>
--- parent 2 children --- 
   <>child page id | child title<>
   <>child page id | child title<>
   <>child page id | child title<>
--- end parent 2 ---
```

This implementation seems to work well but I can't seem to figure out how to modify the functions to return the mark up as above:

```
    // Menu builder function, parentId 0 is the root
function buildMenu($parent, $menuData)
{
   $html = "";
   if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parent]))
   {
      $html .= "
      <ul>\n";
       foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parent] as $itemId)
       {
          if(!isset($menuData['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             $html .= "<li>\n  <a href='".$menuData['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menuData['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a>\n</li> \n";
          }
          if(isset($menuData['parents'][$itemId]))
          {
             $html .= "
             <li>\n  <a href='".$menuData['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menuData['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a> \n";
             $html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData);
             $html .= "</li> \n";
          }
       }
       $html .= "</ul> \n";
   }
   return $html;
}
echo buildMenu(0, $menuData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure seems bizarre. Best I can tell, your $menuData structure is like this:

```
$menuData = array(
  "parents" => array( ... ),
  "items" => array( 
    0 => array( "link" => "...", "title" => "...", ... ),
    1 => array( "link" => "...", "title" => "...", ... )
  )
);
```

In hierarchical structures I've built, they looked more like this:

```
$menuData = array(
    array( "id" => 1, parent_id => 0, "link" => "...", "title" => "...", ... ),
    array( "id" => 2, parent_id => 1, "link" => "...", "title" => "...", ... )
  )
);
```

Maybe this is a constraint on the context you're working in, but just saying: simpler structure makes simpler code.

As for your recursive algorithm to generate your tree, if indeed it generates what you're looking for (the unordered list structure, at least), you've only to experiment with adding your "<>" and "--" pieces where you want between the `<li>` and `</li>` concatenations. You will have a problem, however, with your asterisk for the "first" parent. If you want to put asterisks to all top level menu items, you should establish an optional parameter on buildMenu, like so:

```
function buildMenu($parent, $menuData, $level = 0);
```

Then modify your recursive call like so:

```
$html .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData, ++$level);
```

And add a condition to detect when $level == 0

```
$html .= "<li>\n  " . ( $level == 0 ? "*" : "") . "<a href='".$menuData['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>".$menuData['items'][$itemId]['label']."</a>\n</li> \n";
```

If you just want an asterisk on the first top-level parent, you're better off just establishing a global variable outside the scope of the function, and setting a one-off flag condition to only output an asterisk the first time the code is called, and never again.

Hope this helps.